# Maximum series resistor value you can place on an ADC with and without a buffer

Tags: adc, buffer

I would like to know what would be the maximum series protection resistor i can place on an ADC with a buffer AND without a buffer. I know that with a buffer you can go up to the hundred kilo-ohm range, But what characteristic should i look for in the data sheet that tells that i should go beyond that.

The ADC i plan on using this on is the [ADS131m08](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m08.pdf?ts=1590914443528)  and the buffer is the [OPA2188](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2188.pdf?ts=1591063846612). Applications will be used to measure differential AC signal at all frequencies the ADS allows(primarily 60Hz, giving it a bit more flexibility). The datasheet of the adc shows an application where a 1k series resistor (one for each input pin) is used.

I need the value so i can plan out the voltage divider and tvs diodes specs.

EDIT:

The input source that is what i am most interested to use with this ADC is a current transformer like the [SCT-013-100](https://www.elecrow.com/download/SCT013-000_datasheet.pdf).

Comment: The worst case input impedance of the ADC inputs seems around \$300\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I didn't bother looking around for the sampling capacitance (charge storage.) But they do, as you say, recommend ***two*** (not one) \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors and a \$10\:\text{nF}\$ bypass cap, for about a \$8\:\text{kHz}\$ 1st order filter corner. You are way below this, at \$60\:\text{Hz}\$. So you can change this anti-aliasing filter, as suits you. But the basic idea is that you want on the order of \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ drive impedance. Buffering helps if you want to increase the input \$R\$.

Comment: Wouldn't placing protection resistor after the buffer be pointless? You are not protecting the buffer and you are protecting ADC already protected by the buffer

Comment: @jonk Thank you, but where did you extrapolate that 300k ohm value? I would like to know if ever i get to design another adc i know where to look. Yes two 1k ohm (one for each input) per channel. Should the resistor also take into account the voltage of the input? like for example wont a 100k ohm resistor destroy a 0.1v AC signal ?

Comment: @Maple yes it will be used as a voltage divider only in the buffer. Without a buffer it would be used as a voltage divider and protection reistor. Im sorry if that was not very clear

Comment: @Jakequin Figure 4. As far as the signal source, you'd need to specify the details about it. Everything is in the details. Driving with less than \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ should be just fine. I'd only start to worry if you increase the source drive impedance much above that.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for pointing that out, I wont mind accepting that if you post it as an answer good sir.

Comment: @Jakequin I would, except that I'm not sure about your input source details to the optional buffer. Without that all I'd be doing is wandering around, mostly. In any case, I'm not looking for points here. I just want to help out where I can.

Comment: @jonk i see, you need the input source. I plan to use it with different sources but i will edit the question to contain a signal source where i am most interested in.

Comment: @Jakequin That would definitely need a buffer. It's output is only a max of about half a volt. Worth the effect to include a opamp buffer, no question in my mind.

Comment: @jonk I was right to plan to place that one to the channel with a buffer. Alright, how were you able to tell that that one needed buffer, may i know? so that i will be able to place the  signal source to appropriate channels of the adc? There are version of that current transformer though that output 1-3V, im not sure if that changes anything

Comment: @Jakequin Well, it's output is a maximum of \$500\:\text{mV}\$. That's already a clue, since the ADC can support (and should support) a wider range. So already you need a voltage gain of about 5 or 6. That's clue 1. The next clue is that this is a coil output, so to speak. And that requires some thinking about matching impedances between the source and the ADC. Basically, a "pre-amplifier." I'd look at loading. But it may be better to use a JFET input to handle this (noise affecting the choice.) Or a BJT input. (Likely not MOSFET input.) But it does mean some kind of pre-amp, here.

Comment: @jonk So for the situation where a buffer is NOT needed, ouput voltage should be higher than the Vref of the ADC and Impedence is already matched to the source. Thank you very much good sir for the details. My next step now is to look into buffers since the one i mentioned is the recommended one, and that one's price does not sit well with me (almost the same price as the ADC )

Comment: @Jakequin That looks like a MOSFET chopper to keep the offset voltage low. Yeah, those cost money. Your source is a transformer output, which almost certainly doesn't need this kind of opamp. I'd be looking elsewhere. Where did you get the recommendation to use it?

Comment: @jonk From [Figure 2 page 6 of this article](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduec1b/tiduec1b.pdf?&ts=1590082864823#page=6). I would hopefully like an op-amp that is suited for a wide range of inputes. Do you have a feature recommendation, so i can have atleast something to start with ?

Comment: @Jakequin I see. That bottom block diagram makes a good point but lacks a differential output, which I think you also want. By the way, your low frequency would mean that CMOS opamps will have very high 1/f (flicker) noise largely because of the surface effects of their Si/SiO2 interface. Chopper stabilization for your case would be nice, I'm realizing now. Slipped my mind, earlier. Though I'm not sure you have to use CMOS here. What this is leading towards is that now I'm realizing I'd need to do a LOT MORE work and know more about your source before I could give useful advice.

Comment: @Jakequin  Time I don't have, right now.

Comment: @jonk just reading the datasheet the ADC already has a buffer it would seem. which activates if i increase the the gain , wont that be redundant?

Comment: @Jakequin Yeah. The ADC is already a differential amplifier. And, technically, could probably be hooked up. But it would almost certainly not be the best arrangement. I think you need to do some careful thinking about impedance matching for good S/N. And, frankly, this looks like a project that deserves some serious care going over datasheets. Time I don't have, right away.

Comment: @jonk oh no no, you really do have to. You already pretty much answered my question. Thank you very much. I really did have a lot of datasheet to go through and if i just went ahead on my first prototype many things will be much clearer on what i need.